# Can I violate the same-origin policy with a Java applet

Tags: java, applet, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I need to request things and get information from other domains.  I know javascript can not do this due to the same origin policy.  My other option is to make proxy requests through my server.  I do not want the requests coming from my server's IP nor do I want to create additional load for my server and would prefer the client do it.

Is it possible to use a Java applet to do this?  Manually configuring security settings is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Java applets do implement the same origin policy, much the same way as Flash.  Java will prevent applet-based cross-origin calls if the target server does not have a properly defined publicly accessible crossdomain.xml.

A simple crossdomain.xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Ahh that's a lot easier.  I once read that you can sign a Java applet to have it to do cross domain requests.  Can I utilize a crossdomain.xml to fetch and manipulate remote data with jQuery as well as manipulate iFrames with origins defined in crossdomain.xml?

Comment: No, for ajax requests, there is the [CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) or JSONP (or proxying).  For cross-origin window communication, there is the [Web Messaging API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/).

Comment: So if I want to request and manipulate other web pages (cross domain) my best bet is to use a Java applet with crossdomain.xml

Comment: I would never suggest using Java (or even Flash) client-side for this sort of thing.  There are potentially serious issues with security.  As far as Java is concerned, applets are a real mess.  If you have even a modest user base, you may find yourself quite frustrated and overwhelmed with support issues, especially for OS X users.  If you are building a new web-based application that relies on Flash or Java, you are most definitely heading down the wrong path.

Comment: Nicholous Thanks.  How else do you suggest manipulating foreign origin web-pages?  I'm literally logging into (or using APIs if available) and aggregating data from remote web services and parsing information to display it to the user in a standard format.  As I stated I do not want to put additional load on my server or potentially risk my server's IP getting banned if a user abuses the service or accidentally clicks something 100 times, so I was going to use an applet.  If they ban themselves its better than banning my server.

Comment: The web services/APIs should support the CORS spec or JSONP.  If they do not, you will need to proxy the information from a server you control.